# How to save product's id to a column of user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, shopping-cart

So I've built a system of products and a shopping cart in my rails app. The goal I have is to associate saved products from a cart with user model.

I'm struggling to find a solution on how could I save ids of the items from a cart from each current_user to the column from user's model?

So in my cart view page there is a list of all added products in a cart and I want to add a save button which will save those products by their ids.
As an example, if current_user ads three products in the cart with ids 1,2,3 and clicks on "Save" button in a cart, I want to be able to save those three ids by integers to the "addedproducts" column of the current_user.
This is part of my cart_controller:

```
def additems
    id = params[:id]
    if session[:cart] then
      cart = session[:cart]
    else
      session[:cart] = {}
      cart = session[:cart]
    end
    if cart[id] then
      cart[id] = cart[id] + 1
    else
      cart[id] = 1
    end
  redirect_to :action => :index
  end
```

and a part of my product controller(generated through scaffold):

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html, :json, :js

  def index
    @products = Product.where(availability: true)
  end 

  def show
  end 

  def new 
    @product = Product.new
  end 

  def edit
  end 

  def create
    @product = Item.new(item_params)
    @product.save
    respond_with(@product)
  end
```

Is this possible to achieve?

(I'm using standard Devise setup if it's of any help)

Answer (score 0):

How you want to save multiple items to a single column "addedproducts" ? I think the best solution is adding  a foreign key to the cart. Making the cart belongs_to a user. And the user having many carts. Just the same way you have probably created a Cart model and an Item model too. With the proper relationship between the two... (If you do that you will have to add a new migration to the cart model with a reference to User.)

Comment: Thanks! Ok, but what if I want to save three items within different columns from a User model?